# Can i Use layout inside a Parallel Route on Next13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to define my dashboard and login page based on authenticate user or not i have rootLayout with

```
<html>
      <body>
        {isLoggedIn ? dashboard : login}
      </body>
</html>
```

my folder structure looks like

```
app/
--@dashboard/
----page.tsx
----layout.tsx
--@login/
----page.tsx
----layout.tsx     
--layout.tsx
```

when i'm developing looks like it works but when i run the build command the layout inside my parallel routes never appears.

I tried to deploy on different environemnts and never works also try to run build with export command to try view my html file generated and my layout never render only the page.tsx inside the parallel routes